# jquery - drag & drop table

Tags: jquery, html-table, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

In jquery how to do the drag and drop of table instead of rows ?

By using  **`var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;`** only getting the rows.

But I want the table to be drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
table.tBodies[0].rows
```

to get the rows inside the desired table than the object (table) that you are looking for is

```
table
```